# Electromagnetic Movement

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I posted this in the r/Physics page on reddit and someone recommended asking you lovely folk.

I'm a prop maker and I need some advice from people in the know please. I have been tasked with creating a circular wooden, examinable table, approx 1 metre diameter that will propel an item (metallic) from on the table to the floor. It also needs to be remote controlled (that's the easy bit!)
The fact that it needs to be examinable rules out any sort of visible apparatus used to push the item.

Ideally it wants to be battery powered (though not essential), so it in essence rules out a linear induction motor (unless anyone can suggest otherwise) as I figure that is too energy hungry. I've considered a 'carriage' that is inside the table on a bungee cord that pulls a neodymium magnet inside to move the item then disengages a few centimetres from the edge of the table. This will only work of course if the item would have kinetic energy to fly off the table once the magnet disengaged.

So 2 questions really:
Will the item have any kinetic energy after the magnet disengages?
Is there another way to (quite violently) push the object off the table using opposing magnetic fields?

Thanks

Comment: your task would be easier if you could hide magnets inside the object you wish to drive off the table; is this possible? also, if the table can be plumbed with compressed air ports (like an air hockey table) the task gets easier still. Is this feasible within the constraints of your task? please advise, this sounds like fun- Niels

Comment: The less friction between the table and your metal object the more kinetic energy, have a very smooth surface and it will fall off . (The fall will not work on a tablecloth). For efficient transfer of energy  I would make a fake "thick" tab;e so that the distance between the metal object and the magnet is small.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. The item in question is going to be a tambourine - with quite a thin rim however I see no reason why said tambourine can't be leaning against a book (which can house another magnet) and have both items fly off the table. Could opposition solve this problem? Love the compressed air idea but table needs to be disconnected from wires / visible links etc. So will most likely be a very shiny, polished top! Thanks again